# How to add Google Analytics per theme?

Tags: 7, google-analytics

Is there a way to add GA per theme. The reason for it is I am using [themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) to switch the theme for mobile users.

I have read that it is possible to add more than one tracking code on a site but would like to split them between Main and Mobile.

Comment: Do you need it, really? Just pushing event is not enough to distinguish them? Two code configs are for environments like a corporation (main code) and it's brands (codes tracking details). For mobile, you can either use built-in GA functionality to display OSes, or push proper event.

Answer (score 4):

To add google analytics to every theme,some manual work is required as:-

1. In your theme's folder ,
2. select a theme in which you want to add google analytics
3. open the theme folder and then create a folder for js files
4. create a js file and include the code provided to you by google for google analytics.
5. save the file and this way google analytics is installed in your theme.
6. follow the same procedure for rest all themes.